# Question about the word "matter" as a verb or noun

Tags: word-meaning

> So the **subject matter** today is how do we pick up our driver's handbook or driver's manual? The driver's manual or handbook is something that usually looks like this. They make it in most states in different languages, so you can get one also in Spanish. They also make it **on different subject matters** . So if you're looking to learn to ride a motorcycle, you can pick it up for your motorcycle as well. As well as CDL and truck manuals, there are handbooks on many different subject matters. The best way to pick one up is to make a trip to your local DMV. All the driver's manuals or handbooks are there for you. You can just pick one up free of charge. If the DMV is a little bit tough to get to, you may want to try to call a driving school. Most driving schools carry copies of all the different manuals and handbooks and they usually will be happy to give them to you. Or you can go online. Most DMV websites will carry different types of handbooks on there and you can get a lot of this information from going online. Those would be the three popular ways of obtaining your driver's handbook, either at the DMV itself, from your local driving school or actually going to the DMV website and reading all about the different subject matter online.

1. When he says **the subject matter today" , does it mean **the important thing that we are going to learn about** ? What part of speech is the word **matter** here? Is it a verb!
2. When he says **on different subject matters** , what does the word **matter** mean here? And what part of speech is it this time? Is it a noun? As far as I percieve, the word **matter** here might be a noun meaning subject. If so, why is he saying **on different subject matters** meaning **on different subjects subjects** !! ?

Comment: In this example, the word "matter" is redundant.  In this context, the noun "subject" means the same thing as the phrase "subject matter".  (There are also other noun meanings of "subject", such as a person who is ruled by a government.)

Answer (score 2):

*Matter* is a count noun here, and *subject* is a noun functioning as an adjective. There can be all kinds of *[matters](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/matter)*, including *matter* as a mass noun. When something is a *subject matter* you know that it is the topic under consideration or the subject for discussion.

It is basically a fixed phrase.

This is different from, say, asking someone:

> What's the matter?

which can open the universe wide as far as possible answers, while

> What's the subject matter?

means "What are we discussing?"

Answer (score 0):

*Subject matter* is a common collocation in English. It means "theme." In the example sentence, *matter* acts as a noun and *subject* acts as an adjective. The pairing of "Adj+N" can form a collocation.